# Java/PrimeFaces synchronize Ajax Update

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces

I am trying to synchronize events on the GUI from my backing bean, in order to measure the actual processing time of a particular ajax update. As ajax is, to my knowledge, being processed asynchronously, I fail to gather the diagnostics data I am looking for. 
Trying my current idea, what I would need to do is execute the second script after the ajax update has been processed.

```
{...
  PrimeFaces pf = PrimeFaces.current();
  pf.executeScript("functionStart('columnMapping')");
  pf.ajax().update("contentForm:tv_main");
  pf.executeScript("functionEnd('columnMapping')");
...}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Cheers,
Giagl

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the call to "functionEnd" into the callback function of ajax. The most likely function you want is "onsuccess". Try

```
pf.ajax().update("contentForm:tv_main").onsuccess(pf.executeScript("functionEnd('columnMapping')"));
```

However from your sample code it's hard to know what exactly you are trying to do exactly, maybe you can share a little more information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Benedikt!

Thank you for looking into this. Unfortunately I can't chain an "onsuccess" after the update, as per your description. The only available option in that case, according to IntelliJ, would be "lambda".

I try to get diagnostics data for the PrimeFaces DataTable. DataTable provides hooks for filtering, sorting, page change and others, which I use to measure the access times for these events, but I also need to get the time for populating the DataTable. 
Just before the above code, the DataTable gets the new data and now needs to update on the GUI.

Regards,
Giagl